# servicenow - __encoded_query - some fields not getting filtered

Tags: c#, .net, servicenow

`assigned_to` field is not getting filtered

Code:

`__encoded_query = "assigned_toCONTAINSsteve"`

Actually 2 records containing values with `steve` but not returned with above code. Also `related_records` field is not working with `__encoded_query`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`assigned_to` is a reference field, which stores the sys_id of the referenced sys_user record, but you're querying on what I assume is the display value (`name`). If you want to query for records where the `assigned_to` field refers to a user with a name that contains "steve", try dot-walking through the reference like this:

```
__encoded_query = "assigned_to.nameCONTAINSsteve"
```

For what it's worth, that could be a poorly performing query, you might be better off doing a `STARTSWITH` query, which is more optimizable (from a database standpoint):

```
__encoded_query = "assigned_to.nameSTARTSWITHsteve"
```

Here's what the full SOAP request payload looks like in a test I just ran on a demo instance (where I didn't have any steves, but I had a Fred!):

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <Body>
        <getRecords xmlns="http://www.service-now.com/incident">
            <__encoded_query xmlns="">assigned_to.nameSTARTSWITHfred</__encoded_query>
        </getRecords>
    </Body>
</Envelope>
```

Comment: Please give solution on how to acheive `related_records`

Comment: I want to get the record that contains the value `prj12345` in `related_records` field. I tried with `related_recordsCONTAINSprj12345` but not succeeded. Please provide solution. I also tried with `related_records.nameCONTAINSprj12345`.

Comment: It depends on the type of the `related_records` field. I'm assuming it's a glide_list, in which case it's probably going to store a comma-delimited list of sys_ids, so you'll first need to get the sys_id of the target record and then do a contains search with that (e.g. "related_recordsCONTAINS<sys_id>").

Comment: Yes, I had achieved the task already as you mentioned. Thanks.